# MySQL Syntax Error by combining CASE and LIMIT (only sometimes) - generated by JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am working on a JSF-Web-Application with a MySQL-Database and JPA in a Java EE-Context.

I am using the following JPQL to get some data from the Database. The EntityGenerierteAufgabe has the fields createTime and changeTime. CreateTime is set when the database entry is written. In this case changeTime is NULL. When the database entry is updated changeTime will also be set. Now I want to select from this table and order the entries bei changeTime, if set, otherwise by createTime. AND I want to limit the number of results.

```
String query = "SELECT ga FROM EntityGenerierteAufgabe ga "
        + "WHERE ga.benutzer=:benutzer "
        + "ORDER BY CASE WHEN (ga.changeTime > ga.createTime) THEN ga.changeTime ELSE ga.createTime END DESC";
aufgaben = em.createQuery(query)
        .setParameter("benutzer", benutzer)
        .setMaxResults(6)
        .getResultList();
```

This JPQL is working fine for one User (BrowserSession). If I do some stress testing with jMeter and use more than one Thread (more than one BrowserSession) and calling the JSF-Page, which calls this JPQL, multiple times causes SOMETIMES the following error:

```
Call: SELECT ID AS a1, BEARBEITUNGSZEIT AS a2, CHANGETIME AS a3, CREATETIME AS a4, FORTSCHRITT AS a5, ISTBEENDET AS a6, AUFGABENTYP_ID AS a7, LEVEL_ID AS a8, BENUTZER_ID AS a9 FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = ?) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  DESC LIMIT ?, ?
bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=EntityGenerierteAufgabe sql="SELECT ID AS a1, BEARBEITUNGSZEIT AS a2, CHANGETIME AS a3, CREATETIME AS a4, FORTSCHRITT AS a5, ISTBEENDET AS a6, AUFGABENTYP_ID AS a7, LEVEL_ID AS a8, BENUTZER_ID AS a9 FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = ?) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  DESC LIMIT ?, ?")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.querie
Information:   s.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:495)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
... 124 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC LIMIT 0, 6' at line 1
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor204.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
... 144 more
```

As you can see the SQL-Query is not build correctly. There is an error inside: ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME **WHEN CREATETIME THEN**  DESC LIMIT ?, ?

It is strange because it is working sometimes but sometimes not.

Some extra information:
I am using JSF 2.2. The method with the JPQL is called when the relevant ViewController is instanciated:

```
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
@Named
public class ControllerErfolgskontrolle implements Serializable {

  @Inject
  private SvEnGenerierteAufgabe svEnGenerierteAufgabe;

  private List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> generierteAufgabenBenutzer;

  @PostConstruct
  private void doInit() {
    generierteAufgabenBenutzer = svEnGenerierteAufgabe.getByLimitedSorted(
        getControllerSession().getBenutzer());
  }

  ...
}
```

And the relevant SvEnGenerierteAufgabe-Class with the method creating the JPQL:

```
@Stateless
public class SvEnGenerierteAufgabe {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;

  public List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> getByLimitedSorted(EntityBenutzer benutzer) {

    List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> aufgaben = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT ga FROM EntityGenerierteAufgabe ga "
            + "WHERE ga.benutzer=:benutzer "
            + "ORDER BY CASE WHEN (ga.changeTime > ga.createTime) THEN ga.changeTime ELSE ga.createTime END DESC";
    aufgaben = em.createQuery(query)
            .setParameter("benutzer", benutzer)
            .setMaxResults(6)
            .getResultList();

    return aufgaben;
  }
}
```

I am using the following Verions:
- Glassfish 4.1 (build 13)
- Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
- MySQL  Version: 5.5.27
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.34

I get it working with multiple calls from different jMeter-Test-Threads when I don't set a limit (setMaxResults(...)) OR when I delete the ordering. Both together is not working in some situations like descriped before.

### UPDATE 1:

I tested Alex JPQL before, too. I have done it now again. It results in the following generated SQL:

```
SELECT ID AS a1, ..., CHANGETIME AS a3, CREATETIME AS a4, ..., 
CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME ELSE CREATETIME END
FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = ?) ORDER BY CASE  
WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME ELSE CREATETIME END DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

This is also working fine. But i get same issues when running penetration tests. Sometimes over 1600 Requests (two parallel threads, each sending 800 Requests) work fine and somethimes I get this issue:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = 2) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGE' at line 1
```

and the generated SQL (After the first THEN CHANGETIME a WHEN CREATETIME follows):

```
SELECT ID AS a1, BEARBEITUNGSZEIT AS a2, CHANGETIME AS a3, CREATETIME AS a4, FORTSCHRITT AS a5, ISTBEENDET AS a6, AUFGABENTYP_ID AS a7, LEVEL_ID AS a8, BENUTZER_ID AS a9, CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = ?) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

I think there is a **synchronazition-problem** or a **transaction-problem** somewhere which results SOMETIMES in a misbuiled SQL, when many requests from different clients will be send. But I don't find the problem.
Has anyone an idea? I would test it an update this question.

Comment: what you are trying to do is very weird. and imho wrong. ORDER BY  -that mean you have 1000 rows with let say ID - and want them to be ordered by ID. By you are trying to set the criteria of ORDER dynamically? that means the you want some of your rows to be ordered by ID and others BY NAME ??? so you have to move your CASE to the SELECT statement. and make any transformation there, and ORDER BY anything that is pretty static for this data table :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String query = "SELECT ga , "
            + " CASE WHEN (ga.changeTime > ga.createTime) THEN ga.changeTime ELSE ga.createTime END as myorder"
            + " FROM EntityGenerierteAufgabe ga"
            + " WHERE ga.benutzer=:benutzer "
            + " ORDER BY myorder DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks. It don't solve the problem which results sometimes in misbuilded SQLs. Refer to my Update 1 in my question.

Comment: so in you error message we can see `ORDER BY CASE  WHEN` that is NOT my query. my query use `ORDER BY myorder` so probably you have another query, so show me that one - I can try to fix that

Comment: That is the joke. I am using your JPQL and it generates the SQL above: `SELECT ga, CASE WHEN (ga.changeTime > ga.createTime) THEN ga.changeTime ELSE ga.createTime END AS myorder FROM EntityGenerierteAufgabe ga WHERE ga.benutzer=:benutzer ORDER BY myorder DESC`

Comment: I am using your JPQL and it generates the SQL above: `SELECT ga, CASE WHEN (ga.changeTime > ga.createTime) THEN ga.changeTime ELSE ga.createTime END AS myorder FROM EntityGenerierteAufgabe ga WHERE ga.benutzer=:benutzer ORDER BY myorder DESC`

Comment: for me it doesn't matter what do you use to generate query string. Is it finally generated? and equal to my query? if yes - then you can never get error message like one you posted in your **update 1**

Comment: JPA is generating the SQLs dynamically at runtime, so I have no chance to ensure that your SQL is taken. Here I see the problem on another tier of the application. So your solution helps me not really, sorry.