# Possible race condition beetween stateless EJBs results in wrong SQL generated by JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, race-condition

I am refering to my last question to this topic which you can find here: [MySQL Syntax Error by combining CASE and LIMIT (only sometimes) - generated by JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700794/mysql-syntax-error-by-combining-case-and-limit-only-sometimes-generated-by-j)

The error stil occurs but I found out some interesting facts. But first of all here is my structure:
I am using JSF 2.2, Java EE, JPA and MySQL. The web application is running in a Glassfish 4.1 Server.

The JSF-View calls a list from the following View-Controller:

```
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
@Named
public class ControllerErfolgskontrolle extends ControllerAbstract {

  @Inject
  private SvEnGenerierteAufgabe svEnGenerierteAufgabe;

  private List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> generierteAufgabenBenutzer;

  @PostConstruct
  private void doInit() {
    generierteAufgabenBenutzer = svEnGenerierteAufgabe.getByLimitedSorted(
            getControllerSession().getBenutzer());
  }

  public List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> getGenerierteAufgabenBenutzer() {
    return generierteAufgabenBenutzer;
  }
}
```

The View-Contorller receives the relevant list (generierteAufgabenBenutzer) from the EJB SvEnGenrierteAufgabe:

```
@javax.ejb.Stateless
public class SvEnGenerierteAufgabe {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;

  public List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> getByLimitedSorted(EntityBenutzer benutzer) {

    String query = "SELECT ga, "
            + " CASE WHEN (ga.changeTime > ga.createTime) THEN ga.changeTime "
            + "      ELSE ga.createTime END AS myorder "
            + "FROM EntityGenerierteAufgabe ga "
            + "WHERE ga.benutzer=:benutzer "
            + "ORDER BY myorder DESC";
    List<EntityGenerierteAufgabe> aufgaben = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object[]> results = null;

    results = em.createQuery(query)
            .setParameter("benutzer", benutzer)
            .setMaxResults(6)
            .getResultList();

    for (Object[] result : results) {
      aufgaben.add((EntityGenerierteAufgabe) result[0]);
    }

    return aufgaben;
  }
}
```

In most cases everything works fine and as expected. But when I do stress testing through jMeter with at minimum two different threads the EntityManager SOMETIMES can not create the MySQL-Query in a right way and it results in a MySQLSyntaxErrorException like this:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = 2) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGE' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT ID AS a1, BEARBEITUNGSZEIT AS a2, CHANGETIME AS a3, CREATETIME AS a4, FORTSCHRITT AS a5, ISTBEENDET AS a6, AUFGABENTYP_ID AS a7, LEVEL_ID AS a8, BENUTZER_ID AS a9, CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = ?) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  DESC LIMIT ?, ?
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=EntityGenerierteAufgabe sql="SELECT ID AS a1, BEARBEITUNGSZEIT AS a2, CHANGETIME AS a3, CREATETIME AS a4, FORTSCHRITT AS a5, ISTBEENDET AS a6, AUFGABENTYP_ID AS a7, LEVEL_ID AS a8, BENUTZER_ID AS a9, CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  FROM ENTITYGENERIERTEAUFGABE WHERE (BENUTZER_ID = ?) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN (CHANGETIME > CREATETIME) THEN CHANGETIME WHEN CREATETIME THEN  DESC LIMIT ?, ?")
    at ...
```

The actual syntax error is the `WHEN CREATETIME THEN` part which doesn't belong there at all.

I have the presumption that there is a possible race condition between some Stateless-Instances with different EntityManager-Instances which results in the fact that the EntityManager sometimes builds wrong SQLs.

**This is only an idea but when I replace @javax.ejb.Stateless with @javax.ejb.Singleton everything works fine.** So my questions is: What am I doing wrong? As I know there is a pool of Stateless-Instances and every client (in this case the ViewController) gets its own instance for the method-call and then the instance goes back to the pool.

Comment: Try using StringBuffer (Thread safe) instead of String and check

Comment: Thanks at first but StringBuffer nothing changed. The problem is still available.

Comment: Each EJB handles only one request at a time.  For the second request, it would use another stateless bean. Race condition wouldn't be the case. In the Singleton, container lock the EJB anyway. Running with 2 threads in the sense, how are you doing that?

Comment: Yes as I know and expecting: EJB handels only one request at a time.
With two threads I mean to Test-Threads at jMeter. The result is that jMeter generates nearly parallel requests and so i suggested that maybe a race condition can be the problem. But from EJB-Spec the Stateless only handels one request at a time like @user3694267 mentioned before. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests: 
I used **Hibernate** as JPA-Provider instead of **EclipseLink** and the result is that the error no longer occurs.

So maybe there is a possible bug in the EclipseLink implementation?

Comment: Now I have tested EclipseLink 2.6.0.RC1 in the same combination and I get the same error. So version 2.6.0 would not solve the problem.